# Upexpected behaviour of list.append() and list.clear in for loop in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, append

I have created a big list in which, I am trying to append 10 lists using for loop.
I have created small list outside the for loop. At beginning of every iteration, I am clearing the small list and then I am inserting any random number from 1 to 10 in small list.
Then, I am appending the small list to the big list, and printing the content of small list.
After the termination of for loop, I am printing the content of big list again. Ideally, the content of the big list and the output from inner print statement should be the same. But it is found that the content of the big list is last iterated element from the small list.
Which is uxplainable.

```
import random as r
def try1():
    biglst = []
    smalllist = []
    for i in range(10):
        smalllist.clear()
        smalllist.append(r.randint(1, 10))
        print(smalllist)
        biglst.append(smalllist)
    print("_____________End of for loop__________")
    for i in biglst:
        print(i)
try1()
```

The screenshot of the output is:
[image]

Whereas the the content of the biglist should be same as the output by print statement in for loop.
Can anybody explain this behaviour?

The output of print statement should be equal to the content of big list. But the big list is copying the value of last iteration of for loop.

Comment: You append same list object in every iteration. biglist ends up with multiple copies of same list which is `[8]` at the end. Print `biglist` in every iteration, after you append `smalllist`

Comment: that said, you can achieve what you want with `biglist = [[random.randint(1, 10)] for _ in range(10)]`

Comment: got it. I could achieve the same in many ways but I wanted to understand the behavior of the code. The explanation is very simple but I could not observe it. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending the same `smallist` object which causes unexpected behaviour in your code.
The reason why is this happening, the `smallist` object you are clearing each iteration is the same object you appened to `biglst`, becuase the `smallist` object you added use the **same referance or id in memory**.
You can verify that by running `id(smallist)` in each iteration.
The soultion is when appending your `smallist` to `biglist`, you should append a **copy** not the **object** itself.

Among what you've asked, you can use this code:

```py
import random as r
def try1():
    biglst = []
    smalllist = []
    for i in range(10):
        smalllist.clear()
        smalllist.append(r.randint(1, 10))
        biglst.append(smalllist.copy()) # a copy of smallist object
        print(biglst)
    print("_____________End of for loop__________")
    print(biglst)
try1()
```

Comment: got it. rather simple explanation but I could not observe at first. Thanks!